# Phonetics - English Pronunciation of Vowels Corpus

Tags: phonetics, corpora, pronunciation, resource-request

I am a physics student so forgive me if I'm not very precise with the language. I am currently taking an English course, and my teacher is specialized in teaching pronunciation. I am interested in checking if the students are objectively improving. I am interested in the vowels:

æ, ɑ, ʌ, ə, a

because as a Spanish speaker, they all sound very similar. I decided to create a sort of voice-recognition tool (actually it would be vowel-recognition). For this I am using the soundwave of those vowels pronounced by English people. I found [this Oxford Corpus](http://www.phon.ox.ac.uk/corpus) with many hours recorded. Here the speakers read some paragraphs.

The problem is that I would spend many hours trimming the audio files in order to extract just the part in which they say the specific vowels I need. I want to ask if any of you knows another Corpus just with vowels, as that would ease my work.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: I think I would advise against that corpus, unless there is a time-indexed transcript to go with the sound files. The problem is that you may not be right in your judgment of which vowel tokens are *æ, ɑ, ʌ, ə*, or *a*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For corpora in general, you can take a look at the [Virtual Language Observatory (VLO)](https://vlo.clarin.eu). Just search for "English vowels" or something and see if you make a find.

Alternative suggestion: There is a [plugin](http://www.praatvocaltoolkit.com/extract-vowels.html) for [Praat](http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/) (the quasi-standard for phonetic analysis among linguists) that provides a script which "extracts the vowels of every selected Sound object and joins them into a new Sound object". I haven't used it  myself so don't know how well it works, but you could give it a try. That way, you could continue to work with your existing corpus - read out full paragraphs seem like a more naturalistic, thus more promising resource than recordings of isolated vowels (if there exists such a corpus).

Comment: I think that plugin should solve my problem. Thanks!